# What is/ how to select "prefetch" for parallel flowable?

Tags: rx-java2, rx-java3

I was reading the parallel flows documentation [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Parallel-flows) and it mentioned:

> By default, the parallelism level is set to the number of available CPUs (Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()) and the prefetch amount from the sequential source is set to Flowable.bufferSize() (128). Both can be specified via overloads of parallel().

I still don't understand the purpose of this prefetch, and why it is so big. I guess this means the operators below it will hold onto more than 1 emissions (by default 128). However, I can't imagine this is a good idea, since downstream operators will effectively be single threaded until we have more than 128 emissions from upstream? (e.g. if we have 130, the first 128 will be prefetched by one thread, and the last 2 will be given to the second one. And all other threads will do nothing.).

I guess smaller objects in faster flowables should have a larger prefetch, since the cost of passing data between the rx chain will cost relatively more, so we want prefetch to be higher. I am not sure which numbers to pick here though.

Comment: Unless you have memory constraints or want to reserve CPU cores, there is no general need to fiddle much with these parameters. `parallel` uses round-robin dispatching of elements between ready parallel rails to keep them all occupied.

Comment: I do have memory constraints (crashing with OutOfMemoryException), and I found a few ways of fixing it: using relatively less common rxjava concepts, therefore this would be useful to understand. Round-robin seems to **contradict** prefetch? Which is why I asked what prefetch is (I don't think its explained anywhere)

Comment: It is the same thing as with any backpressured operator having an internal buffer. It holds up to a maximum number of elements until the downstream, in this case, parallel rails are requesting more. As this buffer gets drained, the upstream is requested more items.